# re-generate random number on reset jquery

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I've looked at all the threads I can find, but struggling.. also quite new to Jquery so forgive my ignorance.

I have a form what generates a random code when you load the page. I managed to get that working fine, however the reset button clears this field and I can't figure out how to get the jquery to re-generate the random code on the click of the reset button.

Here is the HTML and JS...

**HTML**
    
    
     
    
    **ID:**

```
<input class="widg_reset" type="reset" value="RESET FORM">
</div>
</form>
<!--form-->
```

**JS**
    function ID(len) {
    var ID;
    var n = '';

```
for(var count = 0; count < len; count++) {
    ID = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    n += ID.toString();
}
return n;
```

}

```
document.getElementById("w_id").value = 'w' + ID(5);
```

I've created a basic fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/6qov3s4h/1/

Any ideas?

Thanks
Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tagged jQuery, so I'll assume you are able to use jQuery code for this. An easy way to accomplish what you want is to listen for a click on the reset button and run some code after the form has been reset.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Listen for a click on the reset button
    $("input[type='reset']").on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from resetting just yet
        $(this).closest('form').get(0).reset(); // Actually reset the form
        document.getElementById("w_id").value = 'w' + ID(5);
    });
});
```

Here's a JSFiddle that demonstrates this functionality: http://jsfiddle.net/xfswc6aq/